# How to I fix a model I build crooked?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I built a head using the mirror modifier and extruding planes, however I applied the modifier before extruding the body down. Now I have the body build, however it slopes to one side along the y axis, so I can't really cut it in half and then re-mirror it.

Comment: Also, I haven't built the arms or legs yet...pretty much because of this issue.

Comment: Have you tried going back on the operators history, by pressing F3.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) select half of the model even if it's not symmetrical. Unfortunately, once you activate the mirrors modifier the model will look like it's been torn up the middle.

To fix, enable clipping in the modifier panel, then select all of the vertices but the head. View your object from the front (numpad<kbd>1</kbd>), and hit <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate the crookedness away until all of the vertices are aligned straight up the middle.

You may need to do a little tweaking to get it to look right again, but the crookedness should be gone.

If your only blocking out a body, and it's a pretty low density mesh, it might be easier to delete it and start again.